# $cookieStore: how to implement it, and how to destroy it?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, session-cookies

Now I am using `ngCookies` and I need to know how to implement it and how to destroy that data on user log out

I set this function to retrieve the data

```
$scope.localStorageInfo = function() {
    $scope.userDisplayInfoName = $cookieStore.get('username');
    $scope.userDisplayInfoEmail = $cookieStore.get('email');
  };
$scope.localStorageInfo();

$scope.signIn = function () {
        $scope.userDisplayInfoName = $rootScope.name.displayName;
        $scope.userDisplayInfoEmail = $rootScope.name.email;
        $cookieStore.put('username', $rootScope.name.displayName);
        $cookieStore.put('email', $rootScope.name.email);
};
```

so, is that the right way ? and how to destroy that data on user log out and how do I realize if that data has been removed from localStorage ?

Comment: for removing $cookieStore.remove('username');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set:
$cookieStore.put('ItsMe', 12345);

Retrieve:
$cookieStore.get('ItsMe');

Remove:
$cookieStore.remove('ItsMe');
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, it  is right way. you can destroy your cookie using `remove` method:

```
$cookieStore.remove('username');
```

Comment: how do I realize if that data has been removed from localStorage ?

Comment: if you are using  chrome, then press F12,you will get Resource tab near Console tab.click on Resource tab, you will get Cookies menu. search particular cookies for your app(website).